# Interpreting the lm results in R for categorical variables

Tags: r, linear-regression

I created two categorical variables (Fac1 and Fac2) which can take values 1 or 2.  So, I have 4 combinations.  For the combination (1,1) I created 25 gaussian random numbers with mean 12.5 and variance 3, for (1,2) I created 25 Gaussian Random numbers with (37.5,3), for (2,1) another 25 with (62.5,3) and for (2,2) with (87.5,3).

I created the R program and ran the lm Model.

```
twodimfac = read.csv("TwoDimFac.csv")
twodimfac$Fac1 <- as.factor(twodimfac$Fac1)
twodimfac$Fac2 <- as.factor(twodimfac$Fac2)

A = twodimfac[,1:2]
x_with_int = lm(twodimfac[,3] ~ . , data = A)
summary(x_with_int)
```

The result I am getting is

```
Call:
lm(formula = twodimfac[, 3] ~ ., data = A)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.9121 -2.3011  0.2431  1.8639 23.5385 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  12.3355     0.6839   18.04   <2e-16 ***
Fac12        49.5762     0.7897   62.78   <2e-16 ***
Fac22        25.4342     0.7899   32.20   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.948 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9812,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9808 
F-statistic:  2530 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I am interpreting Intercept, 12.33554 as a predictor for (1,1).  For other values, the program shows for (1,2) a value which is 12.3355 + 25.4342 = 37.7697, for (2,1) it predicts 61.91175 (which is sum of the intercept coeff and Fac12 coefficient) and for (2,2) it predicts 87.34596 (which is the sum of all coefficients).

How I can interpret the values?  If I have combination of more than 2 factor variables, how one can interpret the coefficients.  Is there any easy formula/function to get it, rather than guessing?

Comment: Are you familiar with dummy coding of a factor?